# Where can I get more lollipops?

Tags: candy-box-2

I bought three from the candy merchant, found one in the forge and a few in the other house. I planted them all, but is there any way to get more without waiting for the farm (25 minutes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are:

- 3 for purchase from the Candy Merchant.
- 3 in the empty house in plain view.
- 1 in the empty house, hidden under the rug.
- 1 in the forge.
- 1 in the Sorceress's hut.
- 3 from answering the Squirrel's questions.

making a total of **12**.

Comment: There's also a lollipop under the rug in the empty house.

Comment: And one under the carpet. Click on the right side of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 lollipops in the empty house; One on the shelf,  One inside the shelf,  And one under the rug.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a few buying from the merchant, and reduce the price a lot to 50 each if you use the secret easter egg, that is listed here http://www.candyboxwiki.com/wiki/Easter_Egg#Lollipop

Page contents: `magical easter egg 0+*=**~*~**=*+0`